# How does scrapy-redis implement the first request as a post request

Tags: python, scrapy

We know that scrapy can implement post requests by rewriting the start_request function, so scrapy_redis?

Comment: It's a good question! I haven't really touched scrapy-redis but it seems to be overiding scrapy scheduler. Any scheduled request goes to redis and when crawler is looking for somethng to crawl it also pops from redis. AFAIK it should more or less function the same? Are you sure it doesn't work if scheduled in `start_requests`?

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite `start_requests` and then return `self.next_requests()`, as `scrapy-redis` does:

https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-redis/blob/master/src/scrapy_redis/spiders.py#L18